# Binding XML with JAXB annotations

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following XML format:

```
 <repositories>
     <set>
       <id>1</id>
       <name>First</name>
       <spec>data</spec>
     </set>
    <set>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>INFO</name>
       <spec>main</spec>
    </set>
      .
      .
 </repositories>
```

I create the following package-info.java

```
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (
 elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
 xmlns = {}
 )

package website.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

ANd the following classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Repositories {

@XmlElement
private ListofRepositories repositories;

public ListofRepositories getRepositories() {
    return repositories;
}

public void setRepositories(ListofRepositories repositories) {
    this.repositories = repositories;
}

}
```

Wrap the sets

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ListofRepositories {

private List<Sets> set;

public List<Sets> getSet() {
    return set;
}

public void setSet(List<Sets> set) {
    this.set = set;
}

}
```

And the data:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Sets {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String spec;

//get set

}
```

I don't know why this doesn't work. The response is always null. I implemented similar processes with Java and JAXB annotations and i never had this kind of problem. Does anyone knows what is wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: Be clear. You need class structure for above xml or xml for above class structure ?

Comment: I need to retrieve the following xml format. So i need to provide the the exact stucture in order to succed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the above xml, you need following class structure:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="repositories")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Repositories {

@XmlElement
private List<Sets> set;

//getter and setter

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Sets {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String spec;

//getter and setter

}
```

But, according to your class structure you will get following xml:

```
<Repositories>
  <repositories>
    <set>
      <id></id>
      <name></name>
      <spec></spec>
    </set>
    <set>
      <id></id>
      <name></name>
      <spec></spec>
    </set>
    .
    .
    .
  </repositories>
</Repositories>
```

Comment: I just want to retrieve the format i mention in the question. The tag <Repositories> shouldn't be appeared. I try to implement your proposition but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

with JAXB you could also generate these classes from an xsd file -- and check the incoming xml against the xsd (which will show **why** it will not accept it)